# How to add back button on top navigation bar using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, back-button, singlepage

Hi all I am trying to add a back arrow button on top navigation bar just like the image:
[image]

But my current code does not show the the back image at all using css. Could you guys help me make the clickable back button visible ?Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<style>

.abcde {
    -webkit-box-direction: normal
}


.abcde,
.Fresh {
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row
}

.abcde {
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 44px;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 16px
}


.sky14 {
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #262626;
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap
}

</style>
<style>

.abcde .Fresh Mango {
        background-image: url(./backArrow.png);
    }


</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

function MyNavigation()
{

alert("do something here");

}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="abcde" id="abcde">
    <div class="Fresh Mango"><a href="javascript:MyNavigation();"><span class="cherry" aria-label="Back"></span></a></div>
    <h1 class="sky14">Photo</h1>
    <div class="Fresh Orange"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could you guys help me make the clickable back button visible ?

Yep. Here's a very quick made example. Feel free to ask if any questions.

(Since I could not get the `./backArrow.png` from your example, I just used one from the internet).

```css
.abcde {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.sky14 {
  color: #262626;
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.abcde .Fresh.Mango {
  background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/8/8764.svg);
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      function MyNavigation() {
        alert("do something here");
      }
    </script>
    <div class="abcde" id="abcde">
      <div class="Fresh Mango" onClick="MyNavigation();"></div>
      <h1 class="sky14">Photo</h1>
      <div class="Fresh Orange"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many thanks for working example. Could you tell me the advantage of removing javascript:MyNavigation() ?If i want use the same div for different type of navigation (for example home,forward ,top of the page ) is it easier to use your method ? or we some how change <a href=" value to call different functions and change its background image using javascript ?

Comment: No problem. Actually, advantages of "my method" is that 1) js is separated from html, thus 2) it's easier to read the code as you don't need to view through all the page containing js and html to find what is happening on some event, and worry about defining all needed functions before they will be called. But in your case, maybe, it's easier to use inline js function call. Well, I didn't know your case exactly. Still, the main question was about the button visibility. =) @user1788736

Comment: I tried to put back <a href="... but when i click the arrow my function doesn't fire!Is there away to make that image clickable using inline js ?